# Vuex actions, vuex modules and mapActions with custom name

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I am stuck looking how I could use a Vuex action inside a template without typing all the action name, this is how my code lookis like:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({ modules: articles, auth, blabla})
```

my articles.module.js contains actions, getters, etc, one of the actions looks like:

```
[ArticleActions.remote.FETCH_ALL]({commit}) {something axios stuff}
```

It is exported with namespaced true:

```
export const articles = {
namespaced: true,
state: initialState,
mutations,
actions,
getters
};
```

In my component ArticleList.vue I wanna use that action with mapActions:

```
 methods: {
        ...mapActions('articles', [ArticleActions.remote.FETCH_ALL])
 }
```

This works, but I do not wanna use the value of ArticleActions.remote.FETCH_ALL in my template what I wanna due is

```
methods: {
        ...mapActions('articles', [{fetchAll: ArticleActions.remote.FETCH_ALL}])
 }
```

so I would only need:

```
mounted(){fetchAll();}
```

instead of

```
mounted(){ArticleActions.remote.FETCH_ALL();}
```

Can we do it?

Answer (score 5):

After some time I figured it out myself, it was easy actually ...

```
...mapActions('articles', {
                fetchAll: ArticleActions.remote.FETCH_ALL,
            }
        ),
```

I stuck because I was used to the alternative syntax:

```
...mapGetters("articles", [
            'articles',
        ])
```

So I was only trying with [] but the solution is using Objects, hope it helps and sorry.
Now if we do this, it works:

```
mounted(){this.fetchAll();}
```

Comment: Where did ArticleActions come from?

Comment: @JoshuaSwain Hi, it was just an example, ArticleActions.remote.FETCH_ALL is just a string, that string was saved in an Object named remote, which was an object inside ArticleActions, but that's not important, instead of reading ArticleActions.remote.FETCH_ALL you can just read a strng for example 'FETCH_ALL'. Actually this was based on an example I made, you can see the code here: https://github.com/melardev/VueVuexBlog/blob/master/src/store/types.actions.js and https://github.com/melardev/VueVuexBlog/blob/master/src/store/modules/articles.module.js