# In VueJS component mapping vuex getters to a different name not working

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuex

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters('global/train_ticket', [
    { ticketTypeForTrain: 'getTicketType' },
    { ticketFareForTrain: 'getTicketFare' },
  ]),
},
mounted() {
  console.log(this.ticketTypeForTrain + ' ' + this.ticketFareForTrain)
},
```

In the code above I have explicitly named the getters. And when I am trying to fetch them in `mounted` hook I get `undefined undefined`

If I do not name them explicitly, I am able fetch the values like below

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters('global/train_ticket', [
    'getTicketType', 'getTicketFare'
  ]),
},
mounted() {
  console.log(this.getTicketType+ ' ' + this.getTicketFare)
}
```

Why naming getters is not working?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vuex actions, vuex modules and mapActions with custom name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53318668/vuex-actions-vuex-modules-and-mapactions-with-custom-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen in the [docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper):

*If you want to map a getter to a different name, use an object*

So your code should use an object instead of an array, like this:

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters('global/train_ticket', {
     ticketTypeForTrain: 'getTicketType',
     ticketFareForTrain: 'getTicketFare',
  }),
},
mounted() {
  console.log(this.ticketTypeForTrain + ' ' + this.ticketFareForTrain)
},
```